# Configuring cyrus imapd processes via CentOs

Tags: centos, imap, mailman, cyrus

Cyrus launches about 13 or 14 imapd processes, each taking about 4-5mb.

Which configuration file stores the values for min/max imapd processes? There is no documentation this, at least none that I could easily find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in configuring the cyrus.conf file via /etc/cyrus.conf.

See the following section:

```
# UNIX sockets start with a slash and are put into /var/lib/imap/sockets
SERVICES {
  # add or remove based on preferences
  imap          cmd="imapd" listen="imap" prefork=0 
  imaps         cmd="imapd -s" listen="imaps" prefork=0
  pop3          cmd="pop3d" listen="pop3" prefork=2
  pop3s         cmd="pop3d -s" listen="pop3s" prefork=0
  sieve         cmd="timsieved" listen="sieve" prefork=0
```

Modify the prefork values.  I don't use any imap so I'm not going to prefork 0 instances, same goes for pop3 (over ssl).